# Powershell script - How can I get this script to only output values that match a certain string

Tags: azure, powershell, scripting, azure-active-directory, office365

So basically I am current using this script that checks what license is assigned to each account in Azure AD

```
Connect-MsolService

$Users= Import-CSV C:\Users\Ark\Desktop\powershell\test01.csv

$Users|%{Get-MsolUser -UserPrincipalName $_.UPN|select userPrincipalNAme,@{n="Licenses Type";e={$_.Licenses.AccountSKUid}}}
```

The csv file that I am ingesting looks like this

```
|UserPrincipalName|            
|:----------------------|   
|test.user@test.com     |
|test.user2@test.com    |
|test.user1@test.com    |
```

With this scripts it goes through and outputs the correct license info for each account, like so

```
|UserPrincipalName|         Licenses Type      
|:----------------------|:-------------      
|test.user@test.com     |testdomain:SPE_E3
|test.user2@test.com    |testdomain:SPE_F1
|test.user1@test.com    |testdomain:SPE_E3
```

Where I am stuck at is I would like for this to only output users that only have a specific type of license. For example if I would only want users that have a testdomain:SPE_E3 license assigned. What can I do to edit my script that would only output users for that specific license, like so

```
|UserPrincipalName|         Licenses Type      
|:----------------------|:-------------      
|test.user@test.com     |testdomain:SPE_E3
|test.user1@test.com    |testdomain:SPE_E3
```

Comment: Please show us ([in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69748710/edit)) what you created sofar (in order to tell you "*What can I do to edit my script ...*)

Comment: @iRon this is where I'm lost at unfortunately, not too much experience with powershell. Can put together a script to output the licenses but not sure how to go about having it output only users with a specific license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with the "Where-Object" filter as follows:

```
Where-Object {($_.licenses).AccountSkuId -match "SPE_E3"}
```